# Jenkins error when building a python script

Tags: python, jenkins, pip

I am configuring a jenkins project and in build environment step; I have below commands to execute from shell:

```
cd /Users/admin/jenkins
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -r requirements.txt --user
python ./script.py
```

But it's failing with

```
pip: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Locally I have tested script.py and it runs fine, perhaps pip and required modules are installed. But running into issues when setting up same as jenkins job to automate the script.
Any alternates/suggestions for the pip install cmd ?

Comment: If jenkins runs on the same machine you're executing the script locally, then jenkins will have a different environment from what you have. Add a line `echo $PATH` in jenkins script, run `basename $(command -v pip)` and check whether the last directory is included in `PATH` on jenkins run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like pip is not installed in the server/environment where jenkins is running. This is not an issue with `script.py`. You need to [install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). This needs to be done only once though when you set up jenkins, no need to add it to the job configuration.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pip` won't work if pip isn't already installed. Have you tried following the steps here to install pip? https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/